# Why .NET Core's HeaderModelBinder not resolving into a complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

We're building our own custom HeaderModelBinder to convert incoming API request's Header into a complex type.

Upon checking the GitHub repo of .NET Core's HeaderModelBinder, I've found out that, unlike the Body/Content of the API, we cannot pass in a JSON in the API Header and expect it to resolve into a type based on the API Method's Parameter's type

I'm just curious as to why .NET Core did not include this feature/capability on its default HeaderModelBinder class.

Comment: because it's quite strange to put a large content in the header. Json content implies a possible large payload. Usually data in header is just plain text and that's enough for almost cases. If you want it to behave differently, just write your own custom header model binder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!, yes, we are building our own custom model binder, I was just curious since there are no other properties/methods to change the behavior of .NET Core's own HeaderModelBinder. At first I was assuming there might be some possible security concerns if we allow the API's Header to bind to complex type.

Comment: well actually I've just pointed out one possible reason for not designing it the way you want. I'm not so sure about other security issues if any. You can search for more, actually in this case the problem is not just you can whether put json in the header or not but if you can put a large data in the header or not, and if there is any limit in size ...